# Synchronization in Java: Threads Created but Not Executed Synchronously?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, threadpool

I have a Java code snippet that involves creating multiple threads to execute a method, but I'm having trouble understanding the synchronization aspect of it. Here's the code:

```
public class SheepManager {

    private int sheepCount = 0;

    private void incrementAndReport() {
        System.out.print((++sheepCount)+" ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
            SheepManager manager = new SheepManager();
            synchronized (manager){
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                    service.submit(() -> manager.incrementAndReport());
            }
        } finally {
            if(service != null) service.shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

Im reading book OCP  809 they said "We’ve
synchronized the creation of the threads but not the execution of the threads. In this
example, each thread would be created one at a time, but they may all still execute and
perform their work at the same time, resulting in the same type of output that you saw
earlier."
I don't understand the meaning of this sentence, synchronized the creation and not the execution of the threads
Can anyone here explain to me

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronized execution of threads". The whole point of threads is that they execute code asynchronously.

Comment: In this book OCP 809 they said We’ve 
synchronized the creation of the threads but not the execution of the threads. In this 
example, each thread would be created one at a time, but they may all still execute and 
perform their work at the same time, resulting in the same type of output that you saw 
earlier.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am saying. Your threads will not run synchronously. You need to edit your question and explain what do you expect to happen and what actually happened. Please read [mcve]

Comment: **FYI,** The English word, "synchronized" means almost completely the opposite of what Java's `synchronized` keyword means. Things in real life are "synchronized" when they happen at the same time. (E.g., google for "synchronized swimming.") The whole point of Java's `synchronized` keyword is to _prevent_ things from happening at the same time.

Comment: Please do not edit your question so that it asks something different from what you originally asked. That destroys the contex for the answers that people already have given, and it makes it hard for anybody who comes late to the conversation to read and understand the whole thing. If you have a new question after reading the answers, you can post a new "question" to the site.

Answer (score 1):

> In this code, I've synchronized the creation of threads by placing the `service.submit()` calls within a synchronized block.

OK ... so what you have done achieves absolutely nothing.

On the one hand, submission of tasks doesn't require any synchronization.  The `submit(...)` method is thread-safe.  While doing it inside a synchronized block (if done properly: see next point!) ensures that the jobs are submitted in groups of 10, nothing prevents some of the tasks in the starting while the group is still being submitted.

On the other hand, you are synchronizing on a `SheepManager` instance that is thread-confined.  That means that the synchronization will be ineffective!  If two threads were to run `main` simultaneously, the submission of the tasks *could be* more or less interleaved.

But either way, this will NOT cause the task *executions* to synchronize.

---

> However, I'm not sure if this guarantees that the threads will execute in a synchronized manner. Is this approach correct for ensuring synchronized execution, or is there a better way to achieve this?

OK, so there is a big problem here.  Your "execute in a synchronized manner" requirement is ill-defined.   What does that actually mean?

I will *assume* that you want the *tasks* to operate in a thread-safe fashion.

If that is what you mean, then there are no short-cuts.  The task code must be thread-safe.  In this context, that means that the `incrementAndReport` method must be thread-safe.  How do you do that?  In any of the ways that you normally write thread-safe code.  There are many ways to do it, depending on the context.

(You have provided no details on what `incrementAndReport` is supposed to do, but if it simply increments a shared counter on the `manager` object, then declaring the method as `synchronized` many be sufficient.)

<sup>(If you clarify your question to explain what you mean, and/or provide more details, I will update this answer.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can only add **`synchronized`** in signture of method like that that's meaning you want to manage the access of the counter variable:

```
private synchronized void incrementAndReport() {
    System.out.print((++sheepCount)+" ");
}
```

Then your main should be like that:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
            SheepManager manager = new SheepManager();
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                    service.submit(() -> manager.incrementAndReport());
        } finally {
            if(service != null) service.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT is : `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Comment: Thanks ! but in this book OCP 809 they said We’ve 
synchronized the creation of the threads but not the execution of the threads. In this 
example, each thread would be created one at a time, but they may all still execute and 
perform their work at the same time, resulting in the same type of output that you saw 
earlier.I don't understand this part? i think it's related to ThreadPool and Thread Lifecycle

Comment: @ThoạiKiều, Either you're trying to go too fast through the book, or it's not a very good book, or maybe both. It sounds to me as if you are trying to understand what a thread _pool_ does, but you do not yet seem to have a strong understanding of what a _thread_ is.